# How a monoid category of bimodules is constructed by a balanced tensor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, tensor-products

Given a semisimple monoid category $\zeta$ with finitely many simple objects and an algebra $(A,\mu)$, it is claimed that bimodules of $\zeta$ over $A$ with a balanced tensor product $\otimes_A$ is again a monoid category.

ie, for $M,N\in\ _A\zeta_A$, the object $M\otimes_AN\in\ _A\zeta_A$, my question is  how left and right morphism of $M\otimes_AN$ is constructed from its definition, which is actually a coequalizer ?

Comment: You mean the left and right *actions*?

Comment: Yep. I `m reading some physics stuff so might not be rigorous in terminology, my apologize.